# Dyalog APL, sort rows in a matrix

Tags: sorting, matrix, row, apl, dyalog

I would like to sort numbers within each row of a matrix, for example,
`3 3 rho  2 3 1 4 5 7 1 9 8`
should become
`3 3 rho  1 2 3 4 5 7 1 8 9`.

I am new to Dyalog APL, and know
how to generate, via grade
the matrix
`3 3 rho 3 2 1 1 2 3 1 3 2`
from the initial matrix.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to sort numbers …

There is actually no sort primitive in APL (allegedly, Dyalog APL 19 is supposed to get one). Until then, you would use one of the monadic Grade functions (Grade Up `⍋` in this case), which returns an array of its argument's indices (starting at `⎕IO`) permuted such that they can be used as ordered references back into the original array. Provide them (enclosed, and in a fork) to the dyadic Index function `⌷` to reference the items in the original array: `⊂⍤⍒⌷⊢`. The enclosing (with the monadic Enclose function `⊂`) is necessary because when using the Index function `⌷`, references to multiple items conveyed as a plain array of indices would instead be interpreted as a single reference into a multi-dimensional array along a number of axes.

> … within each row of a matrix

Use the dyadic Rank operator `⍤` to apply the monadic sort function defined above successively to the first-level (`1`) sub-arrays of the matrix: `⍤1`

```
      ((⊂⍤⍋⌷⊢)⍤1) 3 3 ⍴ 2 3 1 4 5 7 1 9 8
1 2 3
4 5 7
1 8 9
```

Comment: There was never a plan to add sorting primitives.

Comment: A faster, and probably easier-to-read solution is `{⍵[⍋⍵]}⍤1`